# How to pass parameters to a SSH command?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

I configure a ssh command key like (in a remote mashine M1):

```
command="/usr/bin/nslookup",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-dss DEADBEEFDEADBEEF= mycow@farm.org
```

To allow to run nslookup in M1 from a client machine C1. It works and i can run:

```
C1> ssh -i mylookup_key M1
```

And i get the nslookup execution on M1, but i need to pass parameters to get real work. How can i pass parameters to ssh command key?

p.d: I'm using nslookup as an example of the real program that I want to exec.

Comment: Just put the parameters after "/usr/bin/nslookup " in the string?

Comment: Great, it works, but i get errors when iI try to use parameters on the command like "-h" and ssh treat as own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable which should contain the command passed to `ssh`. For example:

```
command="/usr/bin/nslookup $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding ssh-dss DEADBEEFDEADBEEF= mycow@farm.org
```

Then try:

```
$ ssh -i mylookup_key M1 stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to run a command on the remote machine.
The simple case is to just pass the command as the last parameter to ssh

```
ssh -i mylookup_key M1 nslookup stackoverflow.com
```

But you may need to be careful about quoting and special characters. e.g.

```
ssh -i mylookup_key M1 ./args.sh "1 2 3"
PROG:./args.sh
ARG[1]: 1
ARG[2]: 2
ARG[3]: 3
ssh -i mylookup_key M1 ./args.sh '"1 2 3"'
PROG:./args.sh
ARG[1]: 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enclosing the command in `'` or `"`? Soemthing like

```
ssh host "ls -l -a .."
```

which gives me

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 2011-06-16 12:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root  root  4096 2011-06-16 13:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x 49 mihai mihai 4096 2011-07-14 10:33 mihai
```

meaning that it works